# If $U\nsubseteq W$, then $\text{Ann}(W)\nsubseteq\text{Ann}(U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $U,W$ be sub spaces of $V$. If $U\nsubseteq W$, then $\text{Ann}(W)\nsubseteq\text{Ann}(U)$.
($\text{Ann}$ is [Annihilators - by wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators))

My little attempt:

Suppose that,

$$\{u_1,...,u_n\}$$

Is basis for $U$, and
$$\{w_1,...,w_n\}$$

Is basis for $W$.

$U\nsubseteq W$, then exist vector $u\in U$, which is not in $W$, in other words:

$$u\in U\setminus W$$

and  $\{u,w_1,...,w_n\}$ is linear independent.

We can extend  $\{u,w_1,...,w_n\}$ to $\{s_1,...,s_p \}$ where the last is basis for $U\setminus W$, with $p>n$.

And now what?

Comment: $U\backslash W$ is not a vector space, so it doesn't have a basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Take $u$ in $U$, not in $W$; take $\{{\,w_1,\dots,w_n\,\}}$ a basis for $W$; $\{{\,u,w_1,\dots,w_n\,\}}$ is linearly independent; extend it to a basis $B=\{{\,u,w_1,\dots,w_n,v_1,\dots,v_m\,\}}$ of $V$; define a linear functional $L$ on $V$ by $L(u)=1$, $L(w_i)=0$ for all $i$, $L(v_i)$ arbitrary. Then $L$ annihilates $W$ but not $U$.

Answer (score 3):

There exists $u \notin W$, extend to a basis and take $u^*$: this kills $W$ but not $U$.

Comment: What is $u^*$? Thank you!